# Changing attributes to array elements

Tags: php, laravel

I have used this https://fullcalendar.io/ Full calender jquery plugin.

I have the events table and i can get the events like:

```
public function index()
{
    $events=Event::all();
    return view('index')->with('events',$events);
}
```

`$event->event_date` and `$event->name` will give event date and event name. I need to add the event name to respective date in calendar?

I have tried this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:[
            {
                title:'{{$events[0]->name}}',
                start:'{{$events[0]->event_date}}'
             }
           ]
});
```

This will only give first event in the array. But, How can I get all the events and not just one? because i don't have `title` and `start` in `$events` array? or basically i need just a loop?

Comment: Check the [basic example source code](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/demos/basic-views.html). `events` is an array with attributes `start`, `title` and `end` date.

Comment: @kiran.koduru. i've the events array but not those attributes. i've edited the question if you could check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

```
public function index()
{
    $events=Event::all();
    $keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return ['title' => $item['name'], 'start' => $item['event_date']];
    });
    return view('index')->with('events',$keyed);
}
```

In your blade template

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events:{!! json_encode($events) !!}
});
```

Comment: thanks but it is showing error in console with something like`events:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;New Year&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;2018-01-01&quot;},` and even with this only one event is showing.

Comment: Sorry use the `{!! !!}` so blade doesn't escape the html. I updated my answer.

Comment: but still `$events` is returning only one event.

Comment: Try dd(count($events)) in your controller and see how many events are in your database.

Comment: it is showing 3 events but only one event with `dd($keyed)` is showing only one event the last one.